# Canvas Line Width too thick

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm trying out `canvas` and I can't get the lines to get thinner.

I'm using `lineWidth as .5` but it's still too bold.

```
const c = canvas.getContext('2d');

canvas.width = this.track.width();
canvas.height = 18;

c.beginPath()
c.moveTo(where, 20)
c.lineTo(where, 20)
c.lineTo(where, 0)

// If i go .4 the line starts having opacity
c.lineWidth = .5;
c.stroke()
```

Is there no solution?

This is how my grid looks like

[my grid](http://prntscr.com/oumk7t)

Comment: Your image doesn't work (forbidden).

Comment: You can not have a pixel smaller than 1 pixel. Something else is going on, please update your question with a JSFiddle

Comment: Change the color to a transparent one. This will then appear thinner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Opacity is how a canvas creates the *appearance* of lines narrower than a pixel, because a pixel is (by definition) the smallest unit a canvas works with.

That doesn't mean all hope is lost, however, because this is only a problem depending on what you mean by "pixel".

There's the CSS unit `px`, which corresponds to *what used to be* the smallest actual pixels available on video display devices, typically in the range of 72-96 per inch (28-38 per cm).

And then there are actual device pixels, which are now often half as small or smaller.

The trick to getting sharper lines with a canvas when you've got high-res device pixels is scaling. Use this to figure how much you can effectively scale:

`const scaling = window.devicePixelRatio || 1;`

Suppose the value here is 2 (as it is on my current laptop). If you want to create a canvas that occupies, say, 400px by 300px, create an 800x600 canvas. Then use CSS styling `width: 400px; height: 300px` on your canvas.

Now you'll be able to create sharp half-width lines *so long as the device you're drawing to* supports the higher resolution.

I use this trick many places in the Angular app at https://skyviewcafe.com/. There's a link there to the source code if you want to dig through it to find examples of high-res canvas drawing.

Please note!

You're either have to specify a `lineWidth` of 1 when you mean half-width, or use canvas scaling like this:

```
const context = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
context.scale(scaling, scaling);
```

Be careful with `context.scale()` — its effects are cumulative. If you execute `context.scale(2, 2)` twice in a row with the same context, your scaling factor will be 4, not 2.

`context.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);`

...resets the scaling factor if you want to call `context.scale()` more than once, without the effect being cumulative.

Comment: This really did get me a thinner look, but it's still kind of bold even so

Comment: Here's some extra help in understanding line drawing with a canvas: https://mobtowers.com/2013/04/15/html5-canvas-crisp-lines-every-time/. There's always going to be anti-aliasing on slanted lines, but with care horizontal and vertical lines can be pixel perfect.

Comment: just another question, does context.scale work as a zoom maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
canvas.width = this.track.width;
canvas.height = 18;    

const c = canvas.getContext('2d');
c.beginPath();
c.moveTo(0, 0);
c.lineTo(canvas.width, 18);
c.lineWidth = 0.5;
c.stroke();
```

Answer (score 0):

The canvas is more or less just an image -> bitmap you can't draw half a pixel for your line on that bitmap.

What you can do however is to double the canvas size with `canvas.width` and `canvas.height` and scale it back down with CSS or the HTML tag width and height attribute.

Or use an alpha value like `context.strokeStyle = 'rgba(r, g, b, 0.5)';` that the line appears to have half the thickness.

Also keep in mind that the drawing routine draws lines in between 2 pixels, so adding 0.5 to non floating point values on each x and y coordinate will make the line appear smaller too.